# Why doesn't window.getSelection() on focus work in Chrome in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to use window.getSelection() to return the node when a contenteditable div has been focused.

**html:**

```
<div id="testing" contenteditable="true">
   <p>Click on me while monitoring the console</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#testing').focus(function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection());
});
```

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yftf24g6/

Monitoring the console, I get a text node selection in Firefox but not in Chrome (Selection {type: "None"})

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I'm getting the element to `console.log` in both Chrome and Firefox. What versions are you using?

Comment: Like Alex Pan said, its shown correctly.

Comment: I get an empty selection node.That is because the focus is fired quickly on click, if you add `setTimeout` to it, you can see the selection.

Comment: It gives empty selection when you click first time. But what I noticed is that if you click some where else and then click it back, it gives result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome(as I see) The `focus` event is fired as soon as you click on the editable element before you complete your selection. Adding the `setTimeout` solves the issue, but is an unreliable hack.

I would suggest you use `mouseup` event,

> The **mouseup** event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the *mouse button is released*. Any HTML element can receive this event.

```
$('#testing').mouseup(function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
});
```

<sub>Tested in Firefox(37.0.2) and Chrome(42.0.2311).</sub>

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yftf24g6/1/)**

Comment: I may have to go with the hack because I really want to intercept any attempt to focus the div (whether by mouse, click, touch, or tab) and I'd prefer to do it all in one event. I'll mark this as the accepted answer because it did shed light on what the problem was - thanks!